# dynamic dropdown display unique text based on answer

Tags: php, javascript, html, magento

I am using Magento and using their custom options function. I have some working code but I found out later when I added a second product that the "value" for each custom option increases since it is only the auto increment ID assigned in the DB.

I am hoping that the great people here at stackoverflow can help me find a way to show the custom text for each custom option.

To start here is the select generated by Magento:

```
        <select name="options[6]" id="select_6" 
class=" required-entry product-custom-option" title=""
onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();">
<option value="" >-- Please Select --</option>
<option value="13" >Perfect </option>
<option value="25" >Excellent </option>
<option value="15" >Good </option>
<option value="24" >Poor </option>
<option value="17" >Broken </option></select>
```

Here is my current Javascript

```
    <script language="javascript">
   function displayCondition() {
condition = new Array("Please Select a Condition.",
"<b>Perfect:</b> Text to explain perfect condition!",
"<b>Excellent:</b> Text to explain excellent condition!",
"<b>Good:</b> Text to explain good condition!",
"<b>Poor:</b> Text to explain poor condition!",
"<b>Broken:</b> Text to explain broken condition!"); 
     var getsel = document.getElementById('select_<?php echo $_option->getId();?>').price;
     document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
   }
</script>
```

Lastly the div for it to display in

```
    <div id="divId" name="divName" style="width:100%; text-align:center; color:#FFFFFF; margin-top:25px;"></div>
```

I am open to all suggestions even scrapping this for a better method. Please remember I can not change to much and what is show in the generated code as far as each option is what it is. I haven't been able to find the right file to add other options to them (i.e. name or title) Thank you

---

Started trying this, I feel it is promising. Something isn't right though because it still isn't showing anything.

```
    <script language="javascript">

   function showConditions(sel){   
locations =[ "", /*this remains blank for first selection in drop-down list*/ 
/*option 1*/                 
"<b>Perfect</b> Blah Blah ",
/*option 2*/                
"<b>Excellent</b> Blah Blah ",
/*option 3*/                 
"<b>Good</b> Blah Blah ",
/*option 4*/                 
"<b>Poor</b> Blah Blah",
/*option 5*/                 
"<b>Broken</b> Blah Blah", ];
               srcLocation = locations    [sel.selectedIndex];        
if (srcLocation != undefined && srcLocation != "") {
document.getElementById('divId').innerHTML= srcLocation;   
} 
}
</script>
```

and

```
onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();showConditions(this);"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code I was playing with on the bottom got it to work. I had an extra `</div>` tag that was causing it not to show. Wootz!